# Why isn't my prop logging or being passed in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I made a component called `IconButton` that takes some props and passes any additional props through.

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const IconButton = ({ icon, title, ...props }) => {
    console.log(props); // Actual: {}, expected: { onPress: [function] }
    return (
        <View style={ iconBox } { ...props }>
           <Icon name={ icon } size={ 48 } color="black" />
           <Text>{ title }</Text>
        </View> 
};
```

Then I rendered it:

```
const render = () => (
    <IconButton icon='plus' title='add' onPress={ () => console.log('hi') } />
);
```

However when I tried to log it with `console.log`, `onPress` did not show up; it logged an empty object. Also, it wasn't passed to my `View` because it wasn't calling `onPress` when pressed. But when I pass different props with different types such as numbers and strings, it shows up fine.

Why isn't it being passed to my `View` and why isn't the prop being logged? I'm also using Expo if that may affect anything. I've set up an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/229).

Comment: This is very frustrating, because no one else appears to be having this issue on Google... why is it only myself who can't seem to pass functions through props...

Comment: Not sure of the actual issue, but I usually reference the props on the parent `onPress={this.props.onPress}`. The benefit of this is that you know what props you are expecting, rather than sending everything through.

Comment: agreed. I added an edit with a demo piece of code that allowed callbacks.

I'll post my full code, but I have a feeling it's because of one of my imports or something is breaking how React native works... like vector icons maybe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logging issue is a bug with Expo, which uses `JSON.stringify` and other methods to give an output, but isn't outputting objects correctly. The bug also encompasses functions such as `onPress` here which are part of objects, and causes `console.log` to not log it at all, seen here. The issue is [on GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/168) and is set to be fixed in the next SDK update on June 19, 2017.

Now onto a different issue,`View` doesn't take an `onPress` prop, it's not supposed to be touchable. To have a touchable view, try the following wrappers:

- [`TouchableHighlight`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html), on touch, there's a tint added to the view
- [`TouchableNativeFeedback`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback.html), **Android only**, regular view that responds to touches
- [`TouchableOpacity`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html), on touch, the view opacity is decreased
- [`TouchableWithoutFeedback`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html), on touch there's no visible feedback but accepts taps (you shouldn't use this, all interactions should have visible feedback for a good UX)